# Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm following [c-development-with-docker-containers-in-visual-studio-code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-development-with-docker-containers-in-visual-studio-code/) and when building image via vs-code I'm getting this error:

```
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

I'm running it on Windows 10 environment, why is this happening and where to look at the problems to solve it?

Comment: I assume you are running docker desktop. What do you see when you click on the Docker icon in your system tray? (You should see either *"Switch to Linux containers..."* or *"Switch to Windows containers..."*)

Comment: It says: `docker desktop community` - ver.: 2.4.0.0 (48506), where can I find: "Switch to Windows containers...", what does it mean?

Comment: After switching: `no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18363 in the manifest list entries`

Comment: switch daemon (Docker Engine) `"experimental": true` but now I'm getting: `The command '/bin/sh -c g++ -o myapp main.cpp' returned a non-zero code: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)     
The terminal process r build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t dockerhelloworld:latest "."" terminated with exit code:`